# Integrate Immer with NgRx reducer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, immer.js

Looking at the redux and ngrx, it looks like immer is the recommended library to produce a copy of the state before storing. Following the immer example, I add the following code to my reducer:

```
  on(exampleActions.updateExample, (state, { example }) => {

    return produce((state: ExampleType, draft: ExampleType) => {
      draft.push({ example });
      draft[1].done = true;
    });

  })
```

And typescript complains `no-shadowed-variable`, which conflicts with the example. Additionally, I am unable to return the value without return-type errors.

In cases where `example` is the a multi-level object:

```
const example = {
  a: {
    b: { c: 1 }
  }
};
```

`draft` need to be fully de-referenced as well.

There isn't a lot of examples of immer and the `createReducer` integration as this a recent change for 2019. Should I disable the `no-shadowed-variable` rule for immer or is there a better pattern to confirm that both the `state` and `example` are properly de-referenced. `example` is an object of multiple levels.

Alternatively, I can avoid using immer and use ramda `clone` or attempt to manually deep-copy everything.

Comment: no-shadowed-variable warning could be solved by simply renaming the conflicting variable names

Comment: Can't rename in this case because the variable is needed. I need to pass it to `(state: ExampleType, draft: ExampleType)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [ngrx-etc](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc) solves, with the `mutableOn` function (uses Immer)

```
const entityReducer = createReducer<{ entities: Record<number, { id: number; name: string }> }>(
  {
    entities: {},
  },
  mutableOn(create, (state, { type, ...entity }) => {
    state.entities[entity.id] = entity
  }),
  mutableOn(update, (state, { id, newName }) => {
    const entity = state.entities[id]
    if (entity) {
      entity.name = newName
    }
  }),
  mutableOn(remove, (state, { id }) => {
    delete state.entities[id]
  }),
)
```

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc/blob/master/src/mutable-on/mutable-on.ts), which should you take to the right direction.

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!